# ROS2-Ompl integration build error

Tags: ros2, c++, cmake, ros-humble, ompl-planning

I am a total noob in cpp and linux terminal. I am working to get my little turtlebot3 in simulation to navigate through the map I generated through ros slam. Now I am facing some errors when using tf2 to send path to ros2 , the problem specifically arises from chrono and time headers which are included somewhere in tf2.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <builtin_interfaces/msg/time.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ompl/base/SpaceInformation.h>
#include <ompl/base/spaces/SE2StateSpace.h>
#include <ompl/geometric/planners/rrt/RRTConnect.h>
#include <ompl/geometric/SimpleSetup.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>  
#include <ompl/config.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "nav_msgs/msg/path.hpp"
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h>
#include </opt/ros/humble/include/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp>


namespace ob = ompl::base;
namespace og = ompl::geometric;
 
bool isStateValid(const ob::State *state)
{
    // cast the abstract state type to the type we expect
    const auto *se2state = state->as<ob::SE2StateSpace::StateType>();

   // extract the first component of the state and cast it to what we expect
   const auto *pos = se2state->as<ob::RealVectorStateSpace::StateType>(0);

   // extract the second component of the state and cast it to what we expect
   const auto *rot = se2state->as<ob::SO2StateSpace::StateType>(1);

   // check validity of state defined by pos & rot
   double x = (*pos)[0];
   double y = (*pos)[1];
   double theta = rot->value;  // In SE2, the rotation is represented by a single angle (theta) in SO2.
   

   // Check if the position is within certain bounds
   if (x < 0 || x > 348 || y < 0 || y > 348 || theta<-3.14 || theta>3.14) {
       return false; // State is invalid due to bounds violation
   }
   YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("map.yaml");
   double occt=config["occupied_thresh"].as<double>();
   //double frt=config["free_thresh"].as<double>();
   cv::Mat image = cv::imread("map.pgm", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
   cv::Scalar intensity = image.at<uchar>(cv::Point(x, y));
   //Checks for obstacle
   if(intensity.val[0]<=occt){
       return false;
   }
    // return a value that is always true but uses the two variables we define, so we avoid compiler warnings
    return (const void*)rot != (const void*)pos;
}
 
void plan(const rclcpp::Publisher<nav_msgs::msg::Path>::SharedPtr& path_publisher,const rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr& node)
{
    // construct the state space we are planning in
   auto space(std::make_shared<ob::SE2StateSpace>());

   // set the bounds for the R^2 part of SE(2)
   int mapWidth=384;
   int mapHeight=384;
   YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("map.yaml");
   // Extract parameters
   std::string image_path = config["image"].as<std::string>();
   double resolution = config["resolution"].as<double>();
   YAML::Node originNode = config["origin"];
   double originX = originNode[0].as<double>();
   double originY = originNode[1].as<double>();
   double mapWidthMeters = mapWidth * resolution;
   double mapHeightMeters = mapHeight * resolution;
   
   
   ob::RealVectorBounds bounds(2);
   bounds.setLow(0, originX);
   bounds.setHigh(0, originX + mapWidthMeters);
   bounds.setLow(1, originY);
   bounds.setHigh(1, originY + mapHeightMeters);
   space->setBounds(bounds);

   // construct an instance of space information from this state space
   auto si(std::make_shared<ob::SpaceInformation>(space));

   // set state validity checking for this space
   si->setStateValidityChecker(isStateValid);

   // create a random start state
   ob::ScopedState<> start(space);
   start.random();

   // create a random goal state
   ob::ScopedState<> goal(space);
   std::cout << goal;
   goal[0] = 0.5; // Set X-coordinate of the goal
   goal[1] = -0.5; // Set Y-coordinate of the goal
   // Set the orientation if applicable (e.g., for SE3 planning)
   goal[2] = 0;

   // create a problem instance
   auto pdef(std::make_shared<ob::ProblemDefinition>(si));

   // set the start and goal states
   pdef->setStartAndGoalStates(start, goal);

   // create a planner for the defined space
   auto planner(std::make_shared<og::RRTConnect>(si));

   // set the problem we are trying to solve for the planner
   planner->setProblemDefinition(pdef);

   // perform setup steps for the planner
   planner->setup();

   // print the settings for this space
   si->printSettings(std::cout);

   // print the problem settings
   pdef->print(std::cout);

   // attempt to solve the problem within one second of planning time
   ob::PlannerStatus solved = planner->ob::Planner::solve(1.0);

   if (solved)
   {
       // get the goal representation from the problem definition (not the same as the goal state)
       // and inquire about the found path
       auto solution_path = pdef->getSolutionPath()->as<og::PathGeometric>();
       auto path_msg = std::make_unique<nav_msgs::msg::Path>();
       auto current_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

       //Convert std::chrono::system_clock::time_point to builtin_interfaces::msg::Time
       auto time_msg = builtin_interfaces::msg::Time();
       time_msg.sec = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(current_time).time_since_epoch().count();
       time_msg.nanosec = (current_time.time_since_epoch() % std::chrono::seconds(1)).count();

       path_msg->header.stamp = time_msg;
       path_msg->header.frame_id = "map"; // Set the frame ID as per your requirements

       // Extract states from the solution path and add them to the ROS 2 Path message
       for (std::size_t i = 0; i < solution_path->getStateCount(); ++i)
       {
           const ob::State* state = solution_path->getState(i);
           const auto* se2_state = state->as<ob::SE2StateSpace::StateType>();
           const auto* pos = se2_state->as<ob::RealVectorStateSpace::StateType>(0);
           const auto* rot = se2_state->as<ob::SO2StateSpace::StateType>(1);

           geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped pose;
           pose.pose.position.x = (*pos)[0];
           pose.pose.position.y = (*pos)[1];
           pose.pose.orientation = tf2::toMsg(tf2::Quaternion(tf2::Vector3(0, 0, 1), rot->value));
           path_msg->poses.push_back(pose);
       }

       // Publish the path
       path_publisher->publish(std::move(path_msg));

   }
   else
       std::cout << "No solution found" << std::endl;

}
 
void planWithSimpleSetup(const rclcpp::Publisher<nav_msgs::msg::Path>::SharedPtr& path_publisher,const rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr& node)
{
    // construct the state space we are planning in
    auto space(std::make_shared<ob::SE2StateSpace>());
 
    // set the bounds for the R^3 part of SE(3)
    ob::RealVectorBounds bounds(3);
    bounds.setLow(-1);
    bounds.setHigh(1);
 
    space->setBounds(bounds);
 
    // define a simple setup class
    og::SimpleSetup ss(space);
 
    // set state validity checking for this space
    ss.setStateValidityChecker([](const ob::State *state) { return isStateValid(state); });
 
    // create a random start state
    ob::ScopedState<> start(space);
    start.random();
 
    // create a random goal state
    ob::ScopedState<> goal(space);
    goal.random();
    std::cout<<"GOAL:"<<goal;
 
    // set the start and goal states
    ss.setStartAndGoalStates(start, goal);
 
    // this call is optional, but we put it in to get more output information
    ss.setup();
    ss.print();
 
    // attempt to solve the problem within one second of planning time
    ob::PlannerStatus solved = ss.solve(1.0);
 
    if (solved)
    {
        std::cout << "Found solution:" << std::endl;
        // print the path to screen
        ss.simplifySolution();
        og::PathGeometric& solution_path=ss.getSolutionPath();
        auto path_msg = std::make_unique<nav_msgs::msg::Path>();
        path_msg->header.stamp = node->get_clock()->now();
        path_msg->header.frame_id = "map"; // Set the frame ID as per your requirements

       // Extract states from the solution path and add them to the ROS 2 Path message
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < solution_path->getStateCount(); ++i)
        {
           const ob::State* state = solution_path->getState(i);
           const auto* se2_state = state->as<ob::SE2StateSpace::StateType>();
           const auto* pos = se2_state->as<ob::RealVectorStateSpace::StateType>(0);
           const auto* rot = se2_state->as<ob::SO2StateSpace::StateType>(1);

           geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped pose;
           pose.pose.position.x = (*pos)[0];
           pose.pose.position.y = (*pos)[1];
           pose.pose.orientation = tf2::toMsg(tf2::Quaternion(tf2::Vector3(0, 0, 1), rot->value));
           path_msg->poses.push_back(pose);
       }

       // Pubconst rclcpp::Publisher<nav_msgs::msg::Path>::SharedPtr& path_publisherlish the path
       path_publisher->publish(std::move(path_msg));
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No solution found" << std::endl;
}
 
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   /*rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
   auto node=std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("plan_publisher");
   auto pather=node->create_publisher<nav_msgs::msg::Path>("/plannedpath",10);
   
   
   std::cout << "OMPL version: " << OMPL_VERSION << std::endl;
 
    plan(pather,node);
    std::cout<<"End"<<std::endl;
 
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
 
    planWithSimpleSetup(pather,node);*/
 
    return 0;
}
```

This code is built partially using chatgpt.

This is the cmake build error

```
n file included from /usr/include/c++/11/ctime:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/chrono:42,
                 from /root/ros2_ws/src/mp.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/humble/include/tf2/time.h:40:23: error: ‘chrono’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
   40 | using Duration = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
      |                       ^~~~~~
/opt/ros/humble/include/tf2/time.h:41:24: error: ‘chrono’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
   41 | using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>;
      |                        ^~~~~~
/opt/ros/humble/include/tf2/time.h:43:24: error: ‘chrono’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
   43 | using IDuration = std::chrono::duration<int, std::nano>;
      |                        ^~~~~~
/opt/ros/humble/include/tf2/time.h:45:14: error: ‘TimePoint’ does not name a type
   45 | static const TimePoint TimePointZero = TimePoint(IDuration::zero());
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/humble/include/tf2/time.h:48:1: error: ‘TimePoint’ does not name a type
   48 | TimePoint get_now();
      | ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/humble/include/tf2/time.h:51:1: error: ‘Duration’ does not name a type
   51 | Duration durationFromSec(double t_sec);
      | ^~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/humble/include/tf2/time.h:54:1: error: ‘TimePoint’ does not name a type
   54 | TimePoint timeFromSec(double t_sec);
      | ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/humble/include/tf2/time.h:57:33: error: ‘Duration’ in namespace ‘tf2’ does not name a type
   57 | double durationToSec(const tf2::Duration & input);
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/humble/include/tf2/time.h:60:24: error: ‘TimePoint’ does not name a type
   60 | double timeToSec(const TimePoint & timepoint);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/humble/include/tf2/time.h:63:36: error: ‘TimePoint’ does not name a type
   63 | std::string displayTimePoint(const TimePoint & stamp);
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/chrono:42,
                 from /root/ros2_ws/src/mp.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/ctime:64:11: error: ‘clock’ has not been declared in ‘::’
   64 |   using ::clock;
      |           ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/ctime:65:11: error: ‘difftime’ has not been declared in ‘::’
   65 |   using ::difftime;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/ctime:66:11: error: ‘mktime’ has not been declared in ‘::’
   66 |   using ::mktime;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/ctime:67:11: error: ‘time’ has not been declared in ‘::’
   67 |   using ::time;
      |           ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/ctime:68:11: error: ‘asctime’ has not been declared in ‘::’
   68 |   using ::asctime;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/ctime:69:11: error: ‘ctime’ has not been declared in ‘::’
   69 |   using ::ctime;
      |           ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/ctime:70:11: error: ‘gmtime’ has not been declared in ‘::’
   70 |   using ::gmtime;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/ctime:71:11: error: ‘localtime’ has not been declared in ‘::’
   71 |   using ::localtime;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/ctime:72:11: error: ‘strftime’ has not been declared in ‘::’
   72 |   using ::strftime;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/ctime:80:11: error: ‘timespec_get’ has not been declared in ‘::’
   80 |   using ::timespec_get;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/humble/include/ompl-1.6/ompl/base/PlannerTerminationCondition.h:43,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/ompl-1.6/ompl/base/Planner.h:44,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/ompl-1.6/ompl/geometric/planners/PlannerIncludes.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/ompl-1.6/ompl/geometric/planners/rrt/RRTConnect.h:41,
                 from /root/ros2_ws/src/mp.cpp:6:
/opt/ros/humble/include/ompl-1.6/ompl/util/Time.h: In function ‘std::string ompl::time::as_string(const point&)’:
/opt/ros/humble/include/ompl-1.6/ompl/util/Time.h:82:38: error: ‘localtime’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘locale’?
   82 |             ss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&pt), "%F %T");
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                      locale
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:62,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:3392,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /root/ros2_ws/src/mp.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/11/mutex: In member function ‘bool std::__timed_mutex_impl<_Derived>::_M_try_lock_until(const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, _Duration>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/11/mutex:185:61: error: ‘CLOCK_MONOTONIC’ was not declared in this scope
  185 |           return static_cast<_Derived*>(this)->_M_clocklock(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,
      |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/future:39,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:155,
                 from /root/ros2_ws/src/mp.cpp:13:
/usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable: In member function ‘std::cv_status std::condition_variable::__wait_until_impl(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&, const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, _Duration>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/11/condition_variable:201:45: error: ‘CLOCK_MONOTONIC’ was not declared in this scope
  201 |         _M_cond.wait_until(*__lock.mutex(), CLOCK_MONOTONIC, __ts);
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/thread:44,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:155,
                 from /root/ros2_ws/src/mp.cpp:13:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/this_thread_sleep.h: In function ‘void std::this_thread::sleep_for(const std::chrono::duration<_Rep1, _Period1>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/this_thread_sleep.h:82:18: error: ‘::nanosleep’ has not been declared
   82 |         while (::nanosleep(&__ts, &__ts) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
```

I think that my CMake file is having some problem

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(my_robot_motion_planning)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ompl REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(nav_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2 REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2_geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2_ros REQUIRED)
find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

add_executable(my_motion_planner src/mp.cpp)

target_include_directories(my_motion_planner PRIVATE
  ${OMPL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${rclcpp_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${nav_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${tf2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${tf2_geometry_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${tf2_ros_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${std_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  /root/opencv/opencv/include
  ${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

include_directories(${rclcpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${nav_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${tf2_INCLUDE_DIRS})  # Add this line for tf2
include_directories(${tf2_geometry_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS})  # Add this line for tf2_geometry_msgs
include_directories(${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${OMPL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${tf2_ros_INCLUDE_DIRS})  # Add this line for tf2_ros




link_directories(/root/opencv/opencv/lib)

target_link_libraries(my_motion_planner PRIVATE
  ${OMPL_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
  ${rclcpp_LIBRARIES}
  ${nav_msgs_LIBRARIES}
  stdc++fs
  yaml-cpp
  ${tf2_LIBRARIES}
  ${tf2_geometry_msgs_LIBRARIES}
  ${tf2_ros_LIBRARIES}
  ${std_msgs_LIBRARIES}
)

install(
  DIRECTORY src/launch
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

After getting a comment on what is happening in another forum I did this:
changed the source code of pthread.h from <time.h> to </usr/include/time.h> now it's working.But, I want to know how to make it correct without editing these standard header files?

Comment: Please reduce this down to a small self contained example with instructions so that you problem can be reproduced. The description has a lot of references to partially explained things that might be important.